# How to configure "Find text in workspace" search (Ctrl-Alt-G) in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I find the hotkey Ctrl-Alt-G very useful and I often use it. But unfortunately I could not find a way to configure it to:

- search for whole word only (searching my_var also finds my_var_2)
- search only in certain files (*.c and *.h in my case, it finds occurances also in .map and .list and so on)
- do a case sensitive search

I know how to set these up in standard search window (Ctrl-H) but that has no effect on Ctrl-Alt-G.
Thanks for any help

Comment: _Quick Search_ (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L)

Comment: @howlger: thanks for this hint. This allows to select case sensitive and it seems to ignore .map and .list but it does not do whole word only. I use STM32CubeIDE, can't find out which Eclipse version that is.

Comment: Then you have to use _Search > File..._ (Ctrl+H) with the file name patterns `*.c, *.h`.